# Want to ack message, loosing message while restarting

Tags: java, spring-boot, queue, jms

I am loosing message which is already in process while restarting the server.
I want to ack message and move back to queue the message which is in process while bounce or restarting server. Below is my code. Can anybody help me to resolve this?

```
@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> responseMessageFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(concurrency);
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    return factory;
}

@JmsListener(destination = "${myProj.consumerQueueName}", containerFactory = "messageFactory")
public void recieveMessage(byte[] message) {
    String msg = new String(message);
    try { 
        MdcTranIdUtil.generateTranId(message, counter);
        List<String> myXmlList = null;          
        logger.debug("Consumer receives Message: {}" + msg );
        if (msg.length() > 0) {     
                xmlMy = receiver.transfer(msg);             
                for ( String xml : xmlMy ) {
                    responsePublisher.sendIt(xml, receiver.getMessageProps());

            }
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        errorPublish.send(msg);
        logger.error( "RESPONSE CONSUMER EXCEPTION" + e );
    }
```